# Terraform: Get resource ID from within for_each with conditional

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to only create a resource if the variable `s3_anable_acl` variable is true for each record within a list.  I am struggling to access the ID of a resource from within a for_each loop in a similar way to how I had it working with a count.  Is it possible to do this? If so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the resource code i'm using, attempting to use the `id` value similar to how i originally used it in the count version:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_acl_private" {
  # Original (working) using count, without for_each and conditional
  # count  = length(aws_s3_bucket.s3_buckets)
  # bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_buckets[count.index].id

  # New, only create the resource if s3_enable_acl is true
  for_each = { for i in var.s3_buckets : index(var.s3_buckets, i) => i if i.s3_enable_acl }
  bucket = each.value["id"]
  acl    = "private"
}
```

Variable setup:

```
variable "s3_buckets" {
  description = "List of buckets to create"
  type = list(object({
    s3_bucket_prefix            = string
    allow_terraform_s3_deletion = bool
    s3_bucket_versioning        = bool
    s3_bucket_kms_key_id        = string
    s3_bucket_tags              = map(string)
    s3_bucket_lifecycle         = string
    s3_enable_object_lock       = bool
    # s3_enable_acl is only used in the for_each loop, and was not present in the original 'count' version.
    s3_enable_acl               = bool
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Variable:

```
s3_buckets = [
  {
    s3_bucket_prefix            = "some-bucket-name-acl-enabled"
    allow_terraform_s3_deletion = false
    s3_bucket_versioning        = true
    s3_bucket_kms_key_id        = null
    s3_bucket_tags              = null
    s3_bucket_lifecycle         = "Enabled"
    s3_enable_object_lock       = true
    s3_enable_acl               = true
  },
  {
    s3_bucket_prefix            = "some-bucket-name-acl-disabled"
    allow_terraform_s3_deletion = false
    s3_bucket_versioning        = true
    s3_bucket_kms_key_id        = null
    s3_bucket_tags              = null
    s3_bucket_lifecycle         = "Enabled"
    s3_enable_object_lock       = true
    s3_enable_acl               = false
  },
]
```

I have tried a few things like:

```
for_each = { for i in var.s3_buckets : i.id => i if i.s3_enable_acl }

for_each = { for i in aws_s3_bucket.s3_buckets : i.id => i if var.s3_buckets[index(var.s3_buckets, i)].s3_enable_acl }

bucket = each.key
```

Unfortunately, `id` can usually not be found, or I am using the wrong syntax/misunderstanding how to implement the conditional in a for_each.

Comment: There is no `id` key in the objects.. why are you trying to access it?

Comment: Yea, however i can access the `id` through the resource with `aws_s3_bucket.s3_buckets[count.index].id` , but i'm unsure how to get that working with my for_each loop.   The reason i'm trying to access it, is that when i try to create the s3 buckets without the `id` they are going to destroy currently built s3 buckets.  I'm essentially just trying to create buckets with ACLs only if the conditional is true, so i'm editing my currently working code by adding a conditional. Have i gone down the wrong path to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
for_each = { for idx, val in aws_s3_bucket.s3_buckets: idx => val if val.s3_enable_acl }
```